# How to filter JUnit5 tests with custom annotation

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I'm looking for a way to effectively target JUnit5 integration tests. Tests are run using gradle and all integration test classes are decorated by a custom class level annotation. I can filter them based on their class name pattern or by categorizing them using tag, but is there a way to setup a test suite that targets tests with annotation?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your custom class-level annotation is named `@IntegrationTest`, you have two options.

1. [Meta-annotate](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations) `@IntegrationTest` with `@Tag("integration-test")` and then filter by the `integration-test` tag in your build.
2. Implement your own [`ExecutionCondition`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution) that enables/disables test classes based on the presence of `@IntegrationTest` and whatever other criteria you deem appropriate (for example, an environment variable or JVM system property). As an alternative to writing your own `ExecutionCondition`, you could meta-annotate `@IntegrationTest` with one of the [built-in conditional execution annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution) (such as `@EnabledIfSystemProperty`, `@EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find many alternatives

> https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-conditional-test-execution

for example you can use

```
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "myProperty", matches = "my")
```

and then you can use program arguments or profiles for them in gradle